# Hide movieclip parts that are out of bounds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a game where one takes a picture of their face to use on a character.  I have them zoom in on the picture, but the bitmapdata extends out of its movieclip.  How do I assign bounds to my bitmapdata?

Comment: I decided to try getBounds

Comment: ...and it didn't work

Comment: Since this task is not just relevant to games (I can imagine websites doing this) there may already be an explanation on the main StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to dynamically create a shape with the x, y, width, and height of what you want to be visible, make it a mask and then add it to the display list in front of the bitmap data's movie clip. [See this article on the subject](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/mask/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scrollRect` property of your Bitmap. Here's the [API documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect). You might also be interested in the following [question/answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/is-frustum-culling-necessary-in-a-flash-as3-game/3956#3956).